# Two <ul> functions work together or combined into one?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, soundmanager2

I have two `<ul>` classes.  One is `<ul class"list_songs">` the other is `<ul class"playlist">`

The current setup is this, and it doesnt work good. It will list the songs and play them but it doesnt play the next because each link is like its own island.  Any idea how to just combine the two?

```
<div class="blk_main">
    <div class="tag_main">
        <h2>Music Results</h2></p>
    </div>
<div>
    <ul class="list_song">
    {section name=mp3 loop=$mp3_search}
</div>      
        <div>
        <ul class="playlist">       

                  <li> <a class="sm2_link" href="{$mp3_search[mp3].mp3_url}">{$mp3_search[mp3].song_title|strip_tags}</a></li>
                  </ul>

 </div>
 <div id="control-template">
  <!-- control markup inserted dynamically after each link -->
  <div class="controls">
   <div class="statusbar">
    <div class="loading"></div>
     <div class="position"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timing">
   <div id="sm2_timing" class="timing-data">
    <span class="sm2_position">%s1</span> / <span class="sm2_total">%s2</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="peak">
   <div class="peak-box"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="spectrum-container" class="spectrum-container">
  <div class="spectrum-box">
   <div class="spectrum"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that the first class lists the song results and the other formats it into sound manager.  How can I just combined the two so that they work together to create a real playlist, playnext feature would then work.

SOUND MANAGER SETUP
In my header i have

```
<!-- Page player core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soundmanager2/page-player.css" />
<!-- soundManager.useFlashBlock: related CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soundmanager2/flashblock.css" />


<!-- soundManager API -->
<script src="soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js"></script>

<script>

/* --------

  Config override: This demo uses shiny flash 9 stuff, overwriting Flash 8-based defaults
  Alternate PP_CONFIG object must be defined before soundManager.onready()/onload() fire.
  Alternately, edit the config in page-player.js to simply use the values below by default

-------- */

// demo only, but you can use these settings too..
soundManager.setup({
  flashVersion: 9,
  preferFlash: true, // for visualization effects
  useHighPerformance: true, // keep flash on screen, boost performance
  wmode: 'transparent', // transparent SWF, if possible
  url: 'soundmanager2/'
});

// custom page player configuration

var PP_CONFIG = {
  autoStart: false,      // begin playing first sound when page loads
  playNext: true,        // stop after one sound, or play through list until end
  useThrottling: false,  // try to rate-limit potentially-expensive calls (eg. dragging position around)</span>
  usePeakData: true,     // [Flash 9 only] whether or not to show peak data (left/right channel values) - nor noticable on CPU
  useWaveformData: false,// [Flash 9 only] show raw waveform data - WARNING: LIKELY VERY CPU-HEAVY
  useEQData: false,      // [Flash 9 only] show EQ (frequency spectrum) data
  useFavIcon: false     // try to apply peakData to address bar (Firefox + Opera) - performance note: appears to make Firefox 3 do some temporary, heavy disk access/swapping/garbage collection at first(?) - may be too heavy on CPU
}

</script>

<!-- Page player main script -->
<script src="soundmanager2/page-player.js"></script>
```

Comment: Congrats on your first SO post. Could you add some info and code that describes how you are using soundmanager2?

Comment: Thanks sure I will add it now to my post

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, but in the following link you will find a good example of using nested ul tags:

http://www.ezineasp.net/post/HTML-nested-lists-ol-and-ul-tags.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to list the songs through the playlists, because the way it is currently setup it only recognizes one song and cannot create a ongoing plays of songs